# Need an advice regarding schedule settings of flex instance

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a flex instance which is not always on.
I need an advice how to configure an instance to have always on instance during peak hours?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you just have to raise your minimum price up to the on demand price

Comment: @palebone Does it mean that I have to move instance from flex to standard ?

Comment: I think @palebone was thinking you meant a preemptible instance. Flex shouldn't allow you to have less than 1 active instance, can you verify that your instance is passing health checks leading up to the time where you observe 0 instances?
"The minimum number of instances given to your service. When a service is deployed, it is given this many instances and scales according to traffic. Must be 1 or greater, default is 2 to reduce latency."

Comment: Provide your current configuration for your App Engine Flex so we have more context and are able to help better. I think what @FridayPush shared is the correct way to go in this cases.